# RTC to Git Migration issue

Tags: git, migration, rational-team-concert

My stream has nine components. Every time the same components are not migrated. Although the migration says it is completed successfully, I can start contributing to the repo created.

When I run migration for specific component, it runs successfully, which is not migrated in full migration of stream.

The following error is always reported when I run full migration.

However, I get following errors reportedly on screen:-

SEVERE: Status ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.registry code=1 Plug-in 
com.ibm.team.filesystem.rcp.core was unable to load class com.ibm.team.filesystem.rcp.core.internal.resources.ResourceSharingManager. org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in com.ibm.team.filesystem.rcp.core was unable to load class com.ibm.team.filesystem.rcp.core.internal.resources.ResourceSharingManager. children=[Status ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.registry code=1 Plug-in com.ibm.team.filesystem.rcp.core was unable to load class com.ibm.team.filesystem.rcp.core.internal.resources.ResourceSharingManager. org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.ibm.team.filesystem.rcp.core (455).]
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in com.ibm.team.filesystem.rcp.core was unable to load class com.ibm.team.filesystem.rcp.core.internal.resources.ResourceSharingManager.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)

Some more errors are there related to above types.

I followed following steps to run migration for RTC 5.0.2:-

1. created a new workspace for my stream.
2. replaced the baseline to initial.
3. created a new clone to initial set baseline workspace.
4. updated config.ini for WorkspaceName, Directory, ScmCommand, 
   streamToMigrate.
5. executed migration.

But after successfully migration, two of the components do not migrate.

Comment: Further, I saw a trend in migration logs that the error comes after 15000 change sets are migrated to git.